# Python equivalent of SAS raking macro

Tags: python, sas

I was searching for raking module in python something similar to SAS raking macro.

I found SAS one as below:

http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi25/25/st/25p258.pdf

But not able to understand how it works exactly.

Can anyone help me how to go about it in python or some references?

**Edit1:**

This seems close

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipfn

Thanks

Comment: I think I've found an [useful link](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/3l6t4l/sas_programmer_has_questions/) for you.

Comment: That's useful.I knew that sas macro can be made as a function.But what I was looking is some like of module or package in python similar to sas raking.That would save a lot of time for me instead of line to line migration of sas code to python.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm [ipfn](https://pypi.org/project/ipfn/) is the way to go.