# Is there a way to conduct raking in Python?

Tags: python

I know that in SAS there's a raking macro and in R there's packages like Survey that allow for raking, but is there a way to rake data in Python to account for over/under-representation in data? I've looked at quantipy and ipfn which seem like they might be close. If anyone has experience with those, I'd be interested to hear if it worked.

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/61738151/1840471 it looks like `ipfn` is a good approach.